# Run or Execute External Python Dataframe on powerBi

Tags: python-3.x, powerbi

I have a question and I am stucked by days.
I have to make a report on powerBi but all the data process was done on pandas and i have 2 files .py with the process itself.
How do i run or execute those scripts on powerBi to return a table for process?.
i had tried on powerBi python "idle"
import os
os.system("C:\script1.py")
but it doesn´t work. Could you help me?